# GSEventRegisterEventCallBack - Get notified on view changes

Tags: ios, iphone-privateapi

Has any one used `GSEventRegisterEventCallBack`?

My app runs in background. I want to get notified when a view in foreground app(which is not my app) changes. Is it possible through `GSEventRegisterEventCallBack`?

I am not able to get `GSEventRegisterEventCallBack` work somehow for any event. Any code snippet to assist highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Some information on this subject:

I greped Simulator binaries and found it in couple of places:

- GraphicService. It's defined in there and it's implementation is super simple=. It looks something like:

void GSEventRegisterEventCallback(EventCallback eventCallBack) 
{
   __eventCallBack = eventCallBack;
}

__eventCallBack is global variable.

It looks like it's not used at all on Simulator, but quite actively used on a real device (at lease based on references to this global variable in GraphicalServices)

- In UIKit I found an example how it's used (it's in UIApplicationMain)

GSEventRegisterEventCallback(__UIApplicationHandleEvent)

I would say, your best bet would be to disassemble/decompile UIApplicationMain and UIApplicationHandleEvent.

- Also, I found that it's used in backboardd in BKWorkserverManager.

This is interesting, because it's stanalone service which works hand in hand with Springboard. And since, it's in background there is quite good chance that this will allow to receive events even while being in background.

Comment: Hi Victor - Today we actually tested GSEventRegisterEventCallback and simply kept a NSLog to see whether we get a call back. When in foreground and upto few seconds after we go to back ground, we get callbacks in this function. However once in background we do not get callbacks when events happen on foreground app. I am thinking how I can co-relate purpleeventcall back and get purple port of frontmost app had have it call back to my background application.. No luck so far but trying..

Comment: @Bugivore: I see. Thanks for letting know.